# Word for topics that a council will focus on

Tags: single-word-requests

A council in an organization usually has a general set of tasks that it should fulfill. When council members are elected, they usually define a set of topics they think are *extra* important for the next term. They will focus on these topics.

In Dutch, one can speak of [*speerpunten*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/speerpunt#Dutch) of a council. German has the word [*Schwerpunkten*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schwerpunkt#German). These are defined as *"main point of discussion or policy"* and just *"main point"* in Wiktionary.

Is there a word in English that one can use to talk about this?

Example sentence:

> This year's *[word, plural form]* of the participation council are reducing overtime, improving the work environment and monitoring the company's financial situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *agenda* is the set of items to be discussed at a meeting, though *agenda* can also refer more broadly to someone's intentions. The individual items on which the council intends to focus most of its time (its 'main points' as you put it) are called *priorities*.

> **priority** *noun*
>   1.1 (count noun) A thing that is regarded as more important than others.
>   ‘A number of strategic priorities have been identified and acted upon since 1998.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/priority)

Your sentence would then be:

- This year's priorities of the participation council are reducing overtime, improving the work environment and monitoring the company's financial situation.

Answer (score 1):

See **agenda** at [MERRIAM WEBSTER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agenda), defined as

> a list or outline of things to be considered or done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will go with [Lawrence's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/381960/228832) for the reasons they list in their answer.